# Limit and Offset Joi valdation

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

How to check either both limit and offset are provided or none of them

```
limit: Joi.number().integer(),
offset: Joi.when('limit' ,{is: Joi.exist(),
                  then: Joi.number().integer().required()}),

//This is working if limit is provided check for offset
```

Answer (score 1):

```
limit: Joi.number().integer(),
offset: Joi.when('limit', {
  is: Joi.exist(),
  then: Joi.number().integer().required(),
  otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden().error(new Error("need limit and offset both"))
}),
```

This is working